# Add control to main UI container

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have few expanders in one XAML. There is another main UI application which contains StackPanel.

LocalControl.XAML

```
<UserControl>
     <Expander Name="ExpA">
         <StackPanel>
           <ComboBox />
           <TextBox />
         </StackPanel>
     </Expander>

     <Expander Name="ExpB">
         <StackPanel>
             <ComboBox />
             <TextBox />
             <Button />
         <StackPanel>
     </Expander>
</UserControl>
```

I set DataContext for this Expanders and other UI controls' binding in LocalControl.xaml.cs during initialization. Whenever some event triggers, I want to load these expanders in maincontrol under StackPanel.

I have middle man class that listens for the load and unload events from LocalControl.xaml.cs. Lets call it Manager.cs.

Manager.cs

```
public class Manager {

  public Manager(MainControl mc)
  {
     LocalControl lc = new LocalControl();
     lc.loadMe += loadControl;
  }

  private void loadControl(sender, MyEventArgs e)
  {
      foreach(var exp in e.Expanders){
          mc.SP.Add(exp);
      }
  }
}
```

I have main control where I need to display UI controls in my application.

```
<UserControl>
    <StackPanel Name="SP">
        <!-- Add expanders here  -->
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

How can I make sure that I have loaded this expander in MainControl StackPanel?

Is there anyway I can expose some Property in LocalControl and I use that property in MainControl on demand?

In a nutshell, I want to load small controls under one XAML file into StackPanel control in another XAML file during run-time. I don't want to add these controls in MainControl XAML during compile time. In my application, I have many expanders that need to be added run time.

I hope the question is clear.

P.S: Please disregard all syntaxing issues. My intention is to give some idea what I want to do with this.

Comment: Put 1 Expander in 1 User Control and it becomes so very easy.